# Como restar n números en PSeInt

Tags: pseint

Hola soy nuevo en programación y no entiendo como hacer un programa que reste varios números[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] a la vez.

Comment: Mínimo describe el problema y coloca el código a texto, no en una imagen. Checa [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Talvez este video te puede ayudar.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NvCekw6eltM Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

tengo un metodo que ando retomando y es usar la condicional para (for equivalente en un lenguaje de programacion)

Algoritmo for_o_para

```
definir n,acum,cont,num Como Real
Escribir "¿cuantos numeros va a usar?"
Leer n
cont<-0
Para i<-1 Hasta n Con Paso 1 Hacer
    Escribir "ingrese los numeros a restar"
    leer num
    si acum=0 Entonces
        acum<-num-acum
        cont<-cont+1
    sino
        acum<-acum-num
        cont<-cont+1    
    FinSi
Fin Para
Escribir "el resultado es " acum
Escribir "el contador es " cont //ignora el contador mi profe me obligo a usarlo xd
```

FinAlgoritmo